# BUG: Recommendations Bar on same page as Facebook Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have just added in the new Facebook Recommendations Bar (using the HTML5 version) to a number of blogs and realised that some of them aren't working. After a little digging I managed to pin it down to when I also have the Facebook Comments plugin on the same site. As soon as I comment that out it all works again.

The following is being logged in my console 'FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()'.

None of these sites have anything on the front end we have developed that that use FB.getLoginStatus.

Comment: If this is a bug you should raise it here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Thanks TommyBs, bug has been raised here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/265309220247032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook comments plugin already places the Facebook Javascript SDK. I am guessing you are installing the Recommendations bar along with the Javascript - which means it appears twice on the page and therefore giving you this error.

Try adding the Recommendations bar WITHOUT the Javascript - that is, put only the  bit on a page that has the Facebook comments plugin. It should then work fine.